# inconsistent behavior with "undocumented Matlab" figure handles

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, handle, alpha-transparency

I read the [blog post](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient#comment-368567) on assigning transparency to plot markers.  I tried the code on a simple example and all was well. Then I tried a tight loop, plotting a single point at a time (doing this to assign a different color to each point in the graph), and invariably within a few loop cycles, when I grab the "plothandle.MarkerHandle", it's empty. In these cases, the class of this empty object is `Matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder`
while when the operation is successful, the class is: 
`matlab.graphics.primitive.world.Marker`

The basic loop follows.  `colormatrix` assigns a [r,g,b] color to each data point.

```
hold on
opacity = 0.5; 
for jk = 1:numel(idx
  tmph = plot(foox(jk),fooy(jk),'o','color',colormatrix(jk,:) );
     tmpk = tmph.MarkerHandle;

     tmpk.FaceColorData = uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).* [1,1,1,opacity]');
     tmpk.EdgeColorData = uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).* [1,1,1,opacity]');

end
```

I've tried things like clearing variables every loop, putting in a delay timer, and so on, with no luck.  I'm using Matlab R2015a.

EDIT: here's a simple example.  What I **seem** to be finding is that if I run the entire script, it always fails.  If I  break it into two pieces where noted and execute the second section with a separate key stroke (ctrl-enter or selectall/F9 in the IDE editor), everything works.  And yes, I'm aware that "undocumented features" are risky , but since MathWorks still hasn't figured out that allowing transparency -- and indexed color assignments -- are good things for the `plot` function, I'm still looking for a better workaround than using `patch` to draw each data point.

```
figure
xfoo = 1:10;
yfoo = 2*xfoo;
tmph = plot(xfoo,yfoo,'p','color',[1,0,1]);
hold on
opacity = 0.7; 
%  wait a while here. 
tmpk = tmph.MarkerHandle;
tmpk.FaceColorData = uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).*[1,1,1,opacity]');
tmpk.EdgeColorData =  uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).*[1,1,1,opacity]');
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: The blog post is from Nov 2014. Are you sure the undocumented features still apply to 2015a? That's the thing with undocumented features: they can go away any day. See [this comment](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient#comment-348846), the solution to which didn't work for [this user](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient#comment-348984)

Comment: @AndrasDeak  it works "some of the time"  -- that's what's aggravating me.  Matlab's internals are acting inconsistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the script seems to work if you wait a bit between the `plot` and the retrieval of `tmph.MarkerHandle` suggests that you have the same issue that was reported [on the blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient#comment-348846) by a user running R2014b. Yair suggested to call `drawnow` after the plot:

```
figure
xfoo = 1:10;
yfoo = 2*xfoo;
tmph = plot(xfoo,yfoo,'p','color',[1,0,1]);
hold on
opacity = 0.7; 
drawnow;
tmpk = tmph.MarkerHandle;
tmpk.FaceColorData = uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).*[1,1,1,opacity]');
tmpk.EdgeColorData =  uint8(double(tmpk.EdgeColorData).*[1,1,1,opacity]');
```

The workaround didn't work [for a user running R2015a](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-markers-transparency-and-color-gradient#comment-348984), which doesn't sound promising, but the fact that waiting seems to help for you, is encouraging.

Comment: I added `drawnow` and in a quick test it seems to work.  More news later.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft fingers crossed.

Comment: Yep, worked for a loop over 700 points.  Repeatedly.  So at least for my installation of `MATLAB`, I'm ok.  .--- until the next update...

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Glad to hear that, thanks for the feedback!